# PHP DES ECB with Unix Format

Tags: php, encryption, des

I am working with an application that decrypts a text configuration file that is encrypted with DEC ECB and has an 8 char key. I was able to use MCRYPT to generate encryption results that matches when tested on https://www.tools4noobs.com/.

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv)
```

I believe I have something wrong with encoding.  When I open my encrypted results in notepad, I see the encrypted string (that matches what I would get when using the tools4noobs.com tool.  When I do the same with a sample encrypted file from the app I am working with I get what looks like Chinese characters.

> 剽⚚侱鮡㾆퓼ᦐ㒉勣�竐㉁

When I look at this in Notepad++ I get a sequence that no longer has the Chinese characters and looks more like the encrypted file I generated, but still not an exact match.  Both files are ANSI.  Mine is a single line with Windows (CR LF) line format and the sample to match is Unix (LF).

> }Rš&±O¡›†?üÔ‰4ãR õ‡ßÐzA2ûœbýÇ†¹g#—b¼fÇ!ù

It seems like more than just my line format is wrong.  Any suggestions or direction would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**
I see the request for a better example in the comments.  When comparing results in Notepad++

I should get this, sample data encrypted with target software
[image: Goal]

What I get is this, same data encrypted with same key via my PHP 
[image: My Version w/Same Data/Key]

```
    <?php
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_DES, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $key = "12345678";
   $text = file_get_contents('test.cfg');
   //echo $text;

   $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
   echo $crypttext;

   file_put_contents('test.enc', $crypttext);
   echo "ENCRYPTION COMPLETE"; 


?>
```

**UPDATE 2**

$key = "12345678";

$text

```
[Tone1]

Atonelength = 9
Btonelength = 1
Description = ABC Rescue
record_delay = 1.5
ignore_after = 5
```

**UPDATE 3**

After some research, I believe my issue has to do with file encoding and/or line breaks.  The file outputted that I am trying to match is in UNIX LF, were my attempt is WINDOWS CR LF.  Also the target type is two-line.

When I open both files in Notepad++ that eliminates the Chinese-like characters and I can see the first 10 characters are a match.  When I try to dectypt using online tools it looks like my file and the target file have the same content, just the spacing/format is different.  So I'm close.

**My question is now, is there a way to set the output to UNIX encoding using LF when using MCRYPT and file_put_contents to write it to a file?**

Comment: Can you provide a working MVCE so we can work through this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Without more information this question is going to be closed. It has one of the three close votes necessary already.

Comment: We will need to know the value of `$iv` and `$text`  used when generating the encrypted string and the current encrypted value so we can actually test against it. I have a script ready to go to test various permutations of DES encryption once I have all of the info needed to run it.

Comment: Appreciate your help @John Conde

Comment: John were you able to come up with any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue came down to padding to make the PHP version of the cipher text compatible with the Python-based app's ability to encrypt and decrypt.  Also, was able to do this with the more current openssl vs. the deprecated MCRYPT.

Encrypt:

```
$padded_data = $plaintext . str_repeat("\0",(8-(strlen($plaintext) % 8)));
$encrypted_data =  openssl_encrypt($padded_data,"DES-ECB",$key,$options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
```

Decrypt:

```
$plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext,"DES-ECB",$key,$options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
```